# Get file by path using SharePoint 2010 REST API

Tags: 2010, rest

I'm using the `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` endpoint in the [SharePoint 2010 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) to update file metadata. At the moment I'm referencing the file by ID, but I'd like to use the file's path or filename instead.

Is there a method I can use to reference a file directly by it's path, similar to `getFileByServerRelativeURL()` from SharePoint 2013 onwards?

Comment: are you using javascript or C#?

Comment: Neither - I'm making direct HTTP requests to the REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $filter query string and a property called "Name" like

```
/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/myList()?$filter=Name eq 'Task3'
```

to get only the item which has its name as 'Task3'

Comment: That's not to grab the file, but a list item.

Comment: I tried this and it does also work for libraries, where `Name` refers to the filename.